# Matlab: cumsum and exhaustive unique element's indexing with greedy perspective

Tags: matlab, unique, brute-force, greedy, cumsum

Trying to understand how to manipulate two matrices having the following elements (i ll try to simplify my problem so to be easier to answer) by expanding my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728586/matlab-sum-column-elements-with-restrictions):

First matrix:

```
          8 2 5
Mat1 = [  3 7 8 ] 
          6 5 0
```

Second matrix:

```
         Value(Mat1(1)) Value(Mat1(4)) Value(Mat1(7))
Mat2 = [ Value(Mat1(2)) Value(Mat1(5)) Value(Mat1(8)) ]
         Value(Mat1(3)) Value(Mat1(6)) Value(Mat1(9))
```

Let's presume that Second matrix Values are:

```
              18 22 47
Val.Mat2 = [  28 84 82 ] 
              56 65 0
```

Now we cumsum values of Val.Mat2: `VM2CS = cumsum(sort(Val.Mat2))`, and set a summarize constrain per column `cstr = 100;` with constrain's results gathered on matrix: `result =  sum(VM2CS <= cnstrn);`

```
         18  22   0
VM2CS =  46  87  47
        102 171 129 

result = 2 2 2
```

---

**########################   THE PROBLEM** *(two aspects with ascending complexity)* **#################**

---

- Aspect one: How cumsum can ignore elements of zero(0); So result to be:
  `result = 2 2 1`. I 've tried: `result = sum(cumsum(sort(VM2CS))<=cstr ~=0)` without success.
- Aspect two: `Mat1` elements are repeated within `Mat2` matrix (p.e. Mat1(1) element is the same as Mat1(8) with different value, 18 and 82 respectively. Mat1(6) and Mat1(7) are repeated too.). How can i use only once same element on the final result with perspective to have as many uniques elements per row (with zero(0) excluded)? Expected result should be:

> ```
>                      18 22 47
>  result_expected = [ 28 54  0 ]
>                       0  0  0
> ```

I know that aspect two isn't easy to be answered but pointing out to the solution should also be helpfull. Same useful examples have been proposed by Prof. [Thomas G. Robertazzi](http://web.ece.sunysb.edu/~tom/bio.html#biog) on *[Planning Telecommunication Networks](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0780347021.html)* but I don't have this book in my possession now and I can't afford to buy it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, simply use:

```
result = sum((VM2CS <= cstr) & (VM2CS ~= 0));
```

For the second part, why is the value 56 gone ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 56 is removed cause sum of first two elements with lower value fulfill the constrain. @Smash.